# Prevent Bootstrap 5 Popover from repositioning on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5, popover

I am just working with the default Bootstrap 5 popovers and I'm trying to prevent them from repositioning on scroll, when they get out of view.

For example, the demo they on the Bootstrap docs, "Popover on right", when it is clicked, it opens the popover on the right of the button. But as you scroll down the page, the Popover will reposition to the bottom of the button instead of the right. Is there a way to change or disable the behavior of the Popover to be fixed to the right side of the button?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-content="Right popover">Popover on right</button>
```